# How to convert the following Entity Framework to SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want convert the following Entity Framework code to a SQL command:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<FILES, string>> GetAllActivesFilesForClient(long clientId)
        {​​​​​​​
            var fileList = _db.SIGN_UP_REQUEST_ITEM.Where(d => d.CLIENT_ID == clientId)
               .GroupJoin(_db.USER_FILES, signup => signup.SIGN_UP_REQUEST_ID, userFile => userFile.SIGN_UP_REQUEST_ID, (signup, userFile) => new {​​​​​​​ SIGN_UP_REQUEST_ITEM = signup, USER_FILES = userFile }​​​​​​​)
                .SelectMany(p => p.USER_FILES.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {​​​​​​​ USER_FILES = y, x.SIGN_UP_REQUEST_ITEM }​​​​​​​)
                .GroupJoin(_db.FILES, userFile => userFile.USER_FILES.FILE_ID, File => File.FILE_ID, (userFile, File) => new {​​​​​​​ USER_FILES = userFile, FILES = File }​​​​​​​)
                .SelectMany(p => p.FILES.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {​​​​​​​ FILES = y, x.USER_FILES.USER_FILES }​​​​​​​)
                .GroupJoin(_db.ACCOUNTS_FILES, file => file.FILES.FILE_ID, accountFile => accountFile.FILE_ID, (file, accountFile) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNTS_FILES = accountFile, FILES = file }​​​​​​​)
                 .SelectMany(p => p.ACCOUNTS_FILES.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNTS_FILES = y, x.FILES }​​​​​​​)
                 .GroupJoin(_db.ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM, accountFile => accountFile.ACCOUNTS_FILES.REQUEST_ID, request => request.REQUEST_ID, (accountFile, request) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNTS_FILES = accountFile, ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM = request }​​​​​​​)
                 .SelectMany(p => p.ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM = y, x.ACCOUNTS_FILES }​​​​​​​)
                 .GroupJoin(_db.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountRequest => accountRequest.ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID, accountType => accountType.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID, (accountRequest, accountType) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNT_TYPE = accountType, ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM = accountRequest }​​​​​​​)
                 .SelectMany(p => p.ACCOUNT_TYPE.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new {​​​​​​​ ACCOUNT_TYPE = y, x.ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM }​​​​​​​)
                 .Select(x => new {​​​​​​​ x.ACCOUNT_CREATION_REQUEST_ITEM.ACCOUNTS_FILES.FILES, x.ACCOUNT_TYPE.ACCOUNT_NAME }​​​​​​​)
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(t => new Tuple<FILES, string>(t.FILES.FILES, t.ACCOUNT_NAME)).ToList();
            return fileList;
        }​​​​​​​
```

Can you please help me please to convert it.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on EF logging or use Profiler/SQL Trace/XEvents to see the SQL query EF generates.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28435638)

Comment: It does.  It is simple, reliable, and the only really correct answer.